# How to use count(distinct Col#) in google sheet query

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet query, which works fine, but I need the count function to count the cell only if it is distinct (unique value).
I have a sheet, where Col2 can have repeated IDs, e.g. ID01, ID02, ID01. I need to count ID01 only once, even if the sheet has multiple rows for it. Here is my google query:

```
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheetURL/","sheetname!A1:Z50"), "SELECT count(Col2) where Col1='"&$D$2&"' and Col3 contains 'xyz'")
```

In SQL, there is `distinct` where I can use `count(distinct Col2)` but it does not work in Google sheets.Is there any way where I can count only distinct values of Col2 in my query?

Note that I need distinct cell (Col2), not distinct row or record. `UNIQUE(QUERY(...))` does not seem the right thing for me, as UNIQUE will return unique rows (not cells as I want).

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTUNIQUEIFS()` function.

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(B3:B10,A3:A10,D3,C3:C10,"*xyz*")
```

If you want to use `QUERY()` function then use `UNIQUE()` and `COUNTA()` function.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(QUERY(A3:C10,"select B where A='" & D3 & "' and C contains 'xyz'",0)))
```

[image]

Comment: If the count result is 0, this equation returns 1? any idea why?

Comment: @None Because, `COUNTA()` counts everything, even error values. To avoid that false positive use `ROWS()` function instead. Try- `=ROWS(UNIQUE(QUERY(A3:C10,"select B where A='" & D3 & "' and C contains 'xyz'",0)))`